# Avalonia: DataGrid in TabControl Content Template

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

I want to make automatic creation of tabs with datagrid inside - Amount of Tabs and it's content depends on data files. The tab control has the path TabItem, and the DataGrid sees the path MainWindowViewModel

```
<TabControl Name="TC_TEST" Items="{Binding TtabItem}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" Items="{Binding Content}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

How to generate DataGrid in tabs?